# Is there a name for the unusual transitive status of the verb "to pile"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

One can say: *She piled books on the table*; where *books* is the direct object and *the table* the indirect.

With exactly the same meaning one could say: *She piled the table with books* where the direct and indirect objects change places.

Is there a name for this type of verb? It is not quite the same thing as a ditransitive, where the verb takes two direct objects - as in *He gave her the ring*.

And what other verbs are there like *pile*, apart from the obvious synonyms like *heap*?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be that hard to find other examples "I told the police about the news." "I told the news to the police."

Comment: In "She piled the table with books", isn't _table_ the direct object? I'm wondering whether it's more accurate to say that _direct_ and _indirect_ refer to different nouns in the two examples (but each in the same place) rather than saying that the direct and indirect objects change places (while consistently referring to the books and the table, respectively).

Comment: @Lawrence Yes it is.

Comment: @Laurel I think the verb "to tell" is ditransitive - like "give".  *He told the police what he saw* - two direct objects. That isn't quite the same thing as *He piled the books on the floor*. In that example  "the floor" is clearly an indirect object. It is too long since I studied Latin to say how these various nouns would be declined - but that should perhaps be our guide.

Comment: _piled_ has only a direct object in _she piled books on the table_ - _the table_ is object of preposition _on_ and hence may be moved along with it: _On the table, she piled books_. Similarly for the _with_ version, only _the table_ is an object of _piled_.

Comment: I read *on the table* as a prepositional phrase rather than an indirect object.

Comment: I'm note sure why you say that "He gave her the ring" includes two direct objects. I think that most people would say that "her" is an indirect object, not a direct object.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Isn't it both?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Exactly what I would have thought until I discovered Stack Exchange. But if you search "ditranstive" on this site you will see where I'm coming from.

Comment: The whole issue about what constitutes a DO, an IO, is far from a settled debate. 'The piano had a stool' is not considered to have a DO by some. Similarly for 'He seemed a nice boy.' 'This sculpture resembles an Ent.' And as for the analysis of 'She led them a merry dance' as ditransitive ....

Comment: @WS2 I can't speak for what people say on this site, but it is unusual to say that a verb takes multiple DOs (unless they are in series, of course). For example, Greenbaum (OEG) says that "a ditransitive verb has two objects: an indirect object and a direct object," and Quirk (CGEL) 16.55 says that "ditransitive complementation in its basic form involves two object noun phrases: an indirect object . . . and a direct object."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan My contribution to this site is based on my status as a a fluent native speaker. I am not a linguistics specialist - hence I am a bit at a loss when we get into this degree of analysis. But I do know that the word "ditransitive" exists and that there has been discussion on the site about it. The person you need to try and involve is John Lawler, who is a highly erudite retired linguistics professor, with decades of experience.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the [***Spray/Load* Alternation**](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/spray.pdf)
(Verb class 9.7 in [Levin 1993, *English Verb Classes and Alternations* pp 117-119](https://www.google.com/books/edition/English_Verb_Classes_and_Alternations/6wIZWOrcBf8C?hl=en)).

Some examples of the phenomenon, from the link (which also has a list of verbs that take it). Ungrammatical sentences or phrases are marked with initial asterisk, and references are to other alternations in Levin 93.

- *Jessica sprayed paint on the table.*
- *Jessica sprayed (*on) the table with paint.* (Spray/Load Alternation: 2.3.1)
- *Paint sprayed on the wall.* (Causative Alternation: 1.1.2.1)
- **The wall sprayed with paint*
- *Jessica squirted/splashed/sprayed water at me.* (Conative Alternation: 1.3)
- *a spray of paint* (Zero-related Nominal)
- **a spray of the wall*
- *Jessica loaded boxes on the wagon.*
- *Jessica loaded (*on) the wagon with boxes.*
- **Boxes loaded on the wagon*
- **The wagon loaded with boxes*
- **Jessica loaded/stuffed/crammed boxes at the truck*
- *a load of boxes*
- **a load of the truck*

Compare the *Spray/Load* verbs with the *Fill* verbs, also on the link.

Comment: Congratulations for actually answering the question.

Comment: And thanks particularly for giving it a name, so we can refer to it.

Answer (score 17):

*The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language* p313-318 lists a number of verbs that allow alternative patterns of the form

> verb + NP1 + PP(NP2) / verb + NP2 + PP(NP1)

A sample with the attendant discussion omitted,

> i a. He **presented** a prize to Kim. b. He **presented** Kim with a
> prize.
>
> i TO or WITH *credit entrust furnish issue present provide serve
> supply trust*
>
> ii WITH only *arm equip regale reward saddle*

> ii a. He **blamed** the accident on Kim. b.He **blamed** Kim for the
> accident.

> i a. She **sprayed** paint onto the wall. b.She **sprayed** the wall
> with paint.
>
> ii a. She **loaded** hay onto the cart. b.She **loaded** the cart with
> hay.
>
> i theme or loc *brush cram hang inject pack plant shower smear spread
> sprinkle*
>
> ii theme only *immerse lean place push stand*
>
> iii loc only
> *cover decorate drench litter surround*

> i a. I **engraved** my initials on the ring. b.I **engraved** the ring with my
> initials.
>
> ii a. I **scratched** my initials on the ring. b.∗ I **scratched** the ring
> with my initials.
>
> iii a. ∗I **labelled** my initials on the ring. b.I **labelled** the ring with
> my initials.
>
> i theme or loc *embroider inscribe mark stamp tattoo*
>
> ii theme only *carve copy draw print write*
>
> iii loc only *adorn brand decorate illustrate tag*

> i a. They **hunted** deer in the woods. b.They **hunted** the woods for deer.
>
> ii a. ∗She **searched** her key in her bag. b.She **searched** her bag for her
> key.
>
> i quest or loc *fish hunt mine poach stalk*
>
> ii loc only *check dredge examine inspect investigate
> ransack scour search survey watch*

> i a. He **hit** the stick against the fence. b.He **hit** the fence with the
> stick.
>
> ii a. He **stabbed** his knife into me. b. He **stabbed** me with his knife.
>
> iii a. He **pierced** the pin through my hat. b.He **pierced** my hat with the
> pin.
>
> *bang bash beat hammer jab knock
> pound strike tap thump*

> i a. She **built** a shelter out of the stones. b.She **built** the stones
> into a shelter.
>
> ii a. They **produce** fuel from sugar. b. *They **produce** sugar into fuel.
>
> iii a. ∗I **changed** a bedroom from the attic. b.I **changed** the attic into
> a bedroom.
>
> i goal/source *assemble bake carve cut develop form grow make mould
> sculpt*
>
> ii goal only *compose construct derive design manufacture*
>
> iii source only *alter change fold turn work*

The idea is that these verbs allow alternate patterns of complementation with the same valency (2 complements), but with the semantic role of the direct object and oblique object switched. There doesn't seem to be a special word for this on a level with *monotransitive*, *ditransitive*, etc.

Comment: Brilliant. Just what I was looking for.