# Adverbials-how to recognise them?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> Jim spread a piece of toast with butter.

Is *with butter* an adverbial? And why?

Comment: What do you think adverbials are? What definition are you working with? Why are you confused about this particular example?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/581559/is-there-a-name-for-the-unusual-transitive-status-of-the-verb-to-pile/581610#581610

Comment: No, it's not an adverbial. "With butter" is a complement because it is obligatory for this sense of "spread", which means “coated”. Obligatory items are always complements.

Comment: The question is "is 'with butter' adverbial?" The answer is "Yes, it is - it modifies a verb." The question of whether it is also a complement was not asked. (I suspect this should have been in ELL.)

Comment: @Greybeard No it doesn't modify the verb. It's a complement, not a modifier, i.e not an adjunct (your adverbial). Modifier and complement are distinct syntactic functions. For a constituent to be both simultaneously is a theoretical impossibility.

Comment: @Greybeard Note that "complement" is a syntactic concept, not a semantic one.

Comment: Yes... which is why I mentioned it as irrelevant.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's an adverbial, because it modifies "spread". More specifically, it's an [adverbial complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_complement) because it's needed to make the sentence meaningful.

> *Jim spread a piece of toast.

doesn't make sense without the prepositional phrase. (Note that "spread" doesn't always require an adverbial -- "spread the butter" is meaningful by itself.)

Comment: It's interesting because the object of "[spread](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spread)" is normally the thing you are spreading, not the thing you spread it on: e.g. you talk about "spreading gossip", "spreading a table cloth", "spreading muck/fertilizer/seeds", "spreading disease", "spreading butter on bread". I wonder if that's why you seem to need "with butter" in this example.

Comment: It would be preferable to say that "with butter" is a complement because it is obligatory for this sense of "spread", which means “coated”. Obligatory items are always complements.

Comment: So, if _with butter_ is a complement to _spread_, so is _with this knife_. And that would also make any phrase expressing place or time a complement, since anything that happens has to happen sometime and somewhere. Since _spread_ is a [_spray/load_ verb](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/spray.pdf), there are other constructions as well: _He spread the bread with lard, He spread chocolate lard all over the bread with a pearl-handled knife,_ etc.

Comment: There’s a difference between "with this knife" and "with butter", the former being an instrument adjunct, the latter a complement ( a non-core comp, almost like an indirect object). In your example "chocolate lard" is direct object, the PPs "all over the bread" and "with a pearl-handled knife" both adjuncts, locative and instrument respectively.